# My Internet data speed became slow after rooting, need help

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-y

I've rooted my device, and installed a custom ROM + kernel (after making a backup of the original ROM). My device specs:

```
Kernel: Merruk Technology 2.0
OS: Android GB 2.3
Model: Samsung GT-S5360
```

As the title states: My data transfer speed got pretty much down after that. Any idea what could be behind it, and how to get it fixed?

Comment: It could be the Modem/Baseband, it could be the Kernel, or it could be the ROM I'm afraid. Maybe try flashing the correct modem first, and failing that a new kernel, or just a whole new ROM.

Comment: Download it, make sure it's EXACTLY the right one (should be on XDA) flash through phone in Odin.

Comment: Thanks again RossC, u have a lot reputation. I'm new to stack_exchange, looking for a good rep. any word for me?

Comment: To be completely honest, CyanogenMod is prone to a lot of bugs and unexpected results, especially non official builds, and non stable releases. There's lots of ROMs you could try [on XDA developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-y/development) give a few a shot, and  **don't forget backups**. Make a [tag:nandroid] backup before flashing anything. OR you could just revert back to to the stock ROM.

Comment: i already made back up of Original ROM, then i installed Merruk Technology Kernel from XDA.